# Python - Write multiple JSON files each time user submits the form

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-wtforms, wtforms, wtforms-json

This code writes a file named vip.json. Currently, it is overwriting the same file each time i submit the form. But, I want - Each time i click on submit in my form (which is built in flask) I want new files created for each submission. Something like - vip1.json, vip2.json, vip3.json and so on each time the form is submitted.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request, 
jsonify, json
from forms import RequestForm

@app.route("/home", methods=['POST'])
def home():
form = RequestForm()
employee_id = form.employee_id.data
email = form.email.data
network = form.network.data
app_name = form.app_name.data
vip_name = form.vip_name.data
pool_name = form.pool_name.data
pool_monitor = form.pool_monitor.data
pool_member = form.pool_member.data
load_balance = form.load_balance.data
ssl = form.ssl.data

data={}

data = {
    'Employee ID': employee_id,
    'Email': email,
    'Network': network,
    'App Name': app_name,
    'VIP Name': vip_name,
    'Pool name': pool_name,
    'Pool Monitor': pool_monitor,
    'Pool Member': pool_member,
    'Load Balancing Method': load_balance,
    'SSL': ssl
}

if form.validate_on_submit():
    with open("C:\\pytest\\vip.json",'w') as j:
        json.dump(data, j)

    return render_template ('home.html', title='Home', data=data, form=form, employee_id=employee_id, email=email, network=network, app_name=app_name, vip_name=vip_name, pool_name=pool_name, pool_monitor=pool_monitor, pool_member=pool_member, load_balance=load_balance, ssl=ssl)
else:
    return render_template('request.html', form=form)
```

I had a look online but i could not get anything useful. What will be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `glob` to scan your directory and get a list of all your json files, get the file with the latest version, then iterate it by one for the new file's name:

```
import os
import glob

# Use glob to get a list of existing vip files.
dir = "C:/pytest/"
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, "vip*.json")) # Let's say it returns ["C:/pytest/vip1.json", "C:/pytest/vip2.json", "C:/pytest/vip3.json"]

# Grab the latest vip file.
latest_file = sorted(files)[-1]

# Strip the path so it's just the file's name.
file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(latest_file))[0]

# Extract the number from the file's name.
num = int(file_name.lstrip("vip"))

# Generate your new path.
new_path = os.path.join(dir, "vip{}.json".format(num + 1))
# Output of new_path: C:/pytest/vip4.json
```

You may need additional error checking, like if `num` is really a number or if there are no existing files then to default `num` to `1`, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Beautiful piece of explanation. Thank You very much! Works exactly how i wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best way to do it, but you can append a UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier) if you do this:

```
import uuid
if form.validate_on_submit():
    filename "vip-"+str(uuid.uuid4())+".json"
    with open("C:\\pytest\\"+filename,'w') as j:
        json.dump(data, j)
```

The probability of clashing is very low, but you can always [check if the file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions) and generate another one if it does.

If you want to serialize, you can do it by:

- Storing a pickle that has your filecount
- Storing the current count in a database

  - I do not know anything about flask or the ORM you are using (if you are), so I'll leave that up to you
- Using the information in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory) to get a list of the files and add add `1` to `len(list of files)` to get your count (this assumes that only these files exist in the directory)
- Use the same SO post to fetch the list of files, use `RegEx` to filter out files matching your particular pattern, then add 1 to the highest

To use the pickle approach, go to the directory where your python file is, and run this once:

```
import pickle
counter=1;
with open("vip_counter.pickle", "wb") as p:
    pickle.dump(p, counter)
```

This will store a `vip_counter.pickle` in your file system, where the script is run **make sure that the pickle file is in the right spot**

Every time before you exit, you need to update the file in the same fashion:

```
with open("vip_counter.pickle", "rb")as p:
    counter=pickle.load()
#counter is now loaded
counter+=1 #increment your counter before the new filesave
#your code here

#save your pickle back again :)
with open("vip_counter.pickle", "wb") as p:
    pickle.dump(p, counter)
```

Comment: Thanks @robotHamster. Works like a charm. Fixes for the time being. But i'm looking something like human readable, like vip1, vip2, etc. Many thanks for your answer! :) If you could modify this more i would be more than happy, sorry i'm a rookie to python.

Comment: No worries, I think the simplest without knowing what your whole stack looks like is a pickle. I will edit it to include the pickle. Brewing some code....

Comment: No worries :) The other answer posted by @GreenCell also works. If you chose his approach, I wouldn't mind an upvote :)

Comment: I was also thinking `uuid` would be an easy approach! +1

Comment: Thanks @GreenCell, `glob` completely escaped me Lol

Comment: Also, the `uuid` approach is the least disk and memory intensive, especially if there's high enough traffic. Every approach will have its merits

Comment: thanks mate! @robotHamster thanks for explaining it so well. Really appreciate your help :)